# jQuery smooth div scroll scrolling speed much faster on the left than on the right

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to make a "full screen" portfolio on a website at the moment using Smooth Div Scroll (http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/). I've got an issue where the left scrolling is much, much faster than the right one. I noticed in the demos that they are both the same speeds and I can't figure out why it isn't working for the life of me. I've pasted the CSS and JS below. I've also provided a link to the site. If anyone has ideas on how I can solve this I'd be really grateful!

**CSS:**

```
div#full-screen-portfolio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

div.scrollWrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.scrollableArea
{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

div.scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible
{
    width: 130px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url(images/full-screen-arrow-left.png) transparent no-repeat center center;
    zoom: 1; /* Trigger "hasLayout" in Internet Explorer 6 or older versions */
}

div.scrollingHotSpotRightVisible
{
    width: 130px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url(images/full-screen-arrow-right.png) transparent no-repeat center center;
    zoom: 1;
}

body.full-screen-portfolio div#back-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}
body.full-screen-portfolio div#contact-us-area {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
body.full-screen-portfolio div#contact-us-area ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body.full-screen-portfolio div#contact-us-area ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 91px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#full-screen-portfolio").smoothDivScroll({
    visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
    hotSpotScrollingStep: 100
});
```

**Website:**

http://lightboxwebsitedesign.co.uk/newsite/full-screen-portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your CSS file:

```
div.scrollingHotSpotLeft
{
    width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you still experience this problem if you upgrade to [SmoothDivScroll 1.3](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com)? You should consider doing this upgrade anyway since Smooth Div Scroll now supports touch scrolling, which would be great for iPad users that visit your site.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same effect in IE7 (SDS 1.3). It seems the left hotspot scrolls with constant speed - the highest - and doesn't take into account the position of the mouse inside itself.

Test page - http://ateliermoscow.com/ru/collections/osenzima12-13lookbook/